# What is the correct way to handle $scope state and values when changing views in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a Java programmer. I am working now in a mobile app with JavaScript, especifically with Angular.js.

I am totally new to this technology, so I am trying to figure out how to hold values in a controller scope when switching from one view to another that share the same controller.

For example: this is my UserController

```
.controller('UserCtrl',['$scope','UserService',function($scope, UserService) {

    UserService.getAll().success(function(data){
        $scope.items=data.results;
    });

    UserService.get("h7D2wy5lIs").then(function(data){
        $scope.item = data.data;
    });

    $scope.onItemDelete = function (item) {
        UserService.delete(item.objectId);
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item),1);
    };
}])
```

This controller is shared between two different views. When I navigate, the controller reloads every time, and I need to get the default user item from a REST service only once, and then store it in the controller's scope to work with it.

If I modify the item properties in a form, when I go back, it gets the values from the REST API, instead of keeping the state with the new values I provided.

Is there a way to initialize a Controller just once and keep its state through the navigation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically, if I need to store state, I store it in a factory. Then let the controller call to the factory to get the state info.

Comment: Would you say its better to use different controllers for each view and retrieve state from factories?

Comment: @Carlos  When I write my Angular applications, I normally have one view per controller.  You can however, depending on the requirements switch between views using ng-show.  This can have some performance issues because it will compile all information inside the ng-show regardless if it is being viewed at the moment.  When I am getting information from a REST or API I like using factories, and then when I am passing information between controllers I use services.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use services to share data between controllers, in your case, update the UserService:

```
app.factory('userService', function() {
  var items = null;
  var defaultItem = null;
  return {
    getAll: function() {
      if (!items) {
        //get from REST service and set items
      }
      return items;
    },
    getDefaultItem: function(id) {
      if (!defaultItem) {
        //get from REST service and set defaultItem
      }
      return defaultItem;
    },
    ...
  };
});
```

Also note that you might need use promises with [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to handle async calls.

Or you cold set on the $rootScope instead $scope, but you asked for the correct way :)